# How to create mongodb views with mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have a collection that calculates a field based other fields using aggregation and I would like to turn it into a view. How would I implement this using mongoose?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
MyModel.connection.db.createCollection('myViewName', { 
  viewOn: 'existingCollection', 
  pipeline: [/* aggregation pipeline here */] 
});
```

Source: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5694

The complete documentation for views, with samples, are available in: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have a file that contains your model let us say it's an **Order** model
and it's like this :

```
const Order = mongoose.model('Order', {
  customer_id: String,
  order_date: Date,
  product: String,
  quantity: Number,
  price: Number
});
```

and you want to quickly calculate the revenue on each order without querying each order by id or name from the database, however you don't want to store the revenue in your DB (redundant for example or extra space)
so here comes the views beauty.

```
const UserRevenueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  email: String,
  revenue: Number
}, { collection: 'user_revenue', versionKey: false });
```

so with the schema defined above you can write the following view

```
Order.createCollection({
  viewOn: 'orders',
  pipeline: [
    { $lookup:
      {
        from: 'users',
        localField: 'user_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'user'
      }
    },
    { $unwind: '$user' },
    { $group:
      {
        _id: '$user._id',
        name: { $first: '$user.name' },
        email: { $first: '$user.email' },
        revenue: { $sum: { $multiply: [ '$quantity', '$price' ] } }
      }
    }
  ],
  collation: { locale: 'en_US', strength: 2 }
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('View created successfully!');
  }
});
```

This creates a new collection called **user_revenue** as a view of the orders collection, using the same pipeline that we defined earlier. The collation option specifies the collation to use for string comparison, if needed.
This can be now treated as a new model in mongoose .
So you can easily write:

```
// get all revenues sorted by email
UserRevenue.find().sort({email:1})
```